# How to implement optimistic locking from scratch?

Tags: node.js, database, locking, mutex, optimistic-locking

I'm writing to files and I have a very un-contentious workload. However, there is a small chance of a race condition. I want to avoid using a database at this stage and implement optimistic locking on the file system myself. How would I go about this?

Ideally I would just write to the file system and assert some precondition about the version of the file when writing but I can't see any nodejs APIs for doing that.

My initial thoughts to do some kind of locking are that I could do some kind of timestamp locking.

1. Thread A and Thread B both read latest version
2. Thread A writes a version Timestamp1
3. Thread B writes a version Timestamp2
4. Thread A and Thread B wait for reconciliation by Thread C which will look to see if there was more than one version written since the last latest version. If so a queue is created for that file?

Maybe there's a simpler way of doing this?

NB: I intend to implement with nodejs so the threads aren't actual threads. They could be concurrent async tasks or event different processes. I want to avoid using a mutex or in memory queue as they could be different processes.

Comment: Hm, have you considered using filesystem files lock capabilities? At least on Linux that is  [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) syscall. It could be used as a fullfeatured crossprocess mutex. As a bonus, the system kernel guaranties the atomicity of this operation.

Comment: This is pessimistic locking, yes, but it maybe used from any thread or even process. The only way it couldn't be used is over network... but this is already network stuff)

Answer (score 0):

This falls under [file locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#cite_note-11).

Though not optimistic locking, a common strategy is to use the fact that on most file systems creating a directory is a conditional write, ie it will fail if already present. Thus a lock can be acquired by using `mkdir`.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const acquireLock = async (identifier, retries = 5, delay = 1000) => {
  const pathname = `${identifier}.lock`;
  const acquire = () => {
    try {
      fs.mkdirSync(pathname);
      return true;
    } catch {}
  };
  const release = () => fs.rmdirSync(pathname);
  for (let i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
    if (acquire()) return release;
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, delay));
  }
};
```

```
const usage = async () => {
  const lock = await acquireLock("asdf");
  if (lock) {
    console.log("got the lock!");
    lock();
  } else {
    console.log("failed to get the lock!");
  }
};
```